# Use a delegate to merge two functions together

Tags: c#, delegates

I have the following two functions:

```
public static Dictionary<int, string> GetEnumLocalizations<T>()
    where T : struct
{
    return Enum.GetValues(typeof(T))
        .Cast<object>()
        .ToDictionary(enumValue => (int)enumValue, enumObject => ((Enum)enumObject).ToLocalizedValue());
}

public static Dictionary<int, string> GetEnumDescriptions<T>()
    where T : struct
{
    return Enum.GetValues(typeof(T))
        .Cast<object>()
        .ToDictionary(enumValue => (int)enumValue, enumObject => ((Enum)enumObject).GetDescription());
}

public static string GetDescription(this Enum value)
{
    return ...
}

public static string ToLocalizedValue(this Enum value)
{
    return ...
}
```

If I'm not mistaken, it should be possible to merge `GetEnumLocalizations()` and `GetEnumDescriptions()` into one function, and use a delegate parameter to resolve the `((Enum)enumObject).ToLocalizedValue())` and `((Enum)enumObject).GetDescription())` part.

Would that be possible? I got stuck while trying to do so. In pseudo code, I was thinking of something like:

```
public static Dictionary<int, string> GetEnumValues<T>(delegate someFunction)
    where T : struct
{
    return Enum.GetValues(typeof(T))
        .Cast<object>()
        .ToDictionary(enumValue => (int)enumValue, someFunction);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just use this:

```
public static Dictionary<int, string> GetEnumValues<T>(Func<Enum, string> someFunction)
    where T : struct
{
    return Enum.GetValues(typeof(T))
        .Cast<object>()
        .ToDictionary(enumValue => (int)enumValue, enumObject => someFunction((Enum)enumObject);
}
```

Now you should be able to call it this way:

```
GetEnumValues<MyEnum>(x => x.ToLocalizedValue());
```